# Regular expression between characters - last match

Tags: .net, regex

I'm searching for the regular expression that **matches the value between the last `\` and `_`**

Example:

**Input**: `\\\ezbe.local\folder1\folder2\folder3\33248a-48596-a54qsd-4d7d98_2`

**Output**: `33248a-48596-a54qsd-4d7d98`

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow! A few tips: With regex questions, you should always add a tag for the language you're using because regex implementations vary a lot between languages. Also, most people like it if you show what efforts you've undertaken to solve the problem yourself, instead of just asking for a solution. But it's Sunday today, and I'm in a good mood :)

Comment: Hey, thx for the suggestions. I'll take this into account. :)

Comment: Looks like you didn't take them into account...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would be

```
[^\\]*(?=_[^\\]*$)
```

**Explanation:**

```
[^\\]*   # Match any number of non-backslash characters
(?=      # if the following is true after the matched text:
 _       # There is a _
 [^\\]*  # followed only by non-backslash characters
 $       # until the end of the string.
)        # End of lookahead assertion
```